# Why array values appear in impala but not hive?

Tags: hive, impala

I have a column defined as array in my table (HIVE) .

```
create external table rule
id string,
names array<string>
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'stored as parquet
location 'hdfs://folder'
```

Exemple of value in names : Joe|Jimmy

As i query the table in Impala, i retrieve the data but in hive i only have NULL. Why this behavior? I would even understand the inverse.

Comment: You have `id` column and `names` column. What is the delimiter between them?

Comment: Is it necessary to specify delimiter for a parquet file? Anyway the delimiter is a comma (,)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. the data was written from a spark job in string instead of array.